# How can I make an array of objects out of a form?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I have a form with the following structure:

```
<form>
  <div>
     <div>
        <FormLabel />
        <FormSelect />
     </div>
     <fieldset>
       <legend> ---- </legend>
       <div>
          <FormLabel />
          <input></input>
       </div>
       <div>
         <FormLabel />
         <input type='radio'></input>
       </div>
     </fieldset>
     <ProductOrder /> 
     <div>
        <span>+</span>
     </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I'm using React, the problem that I can't solve is this:
When the user clicks in the span, a new  Component spawn, this component is just another set of inputs.

The API that i made for this App needs the following object:

```
{
  providerId : (selectedProviderId),
  isPayed: (boolean),
  orderArrive: (some Date),
  items: [
     { object of each item},
     { the user want to add}
  ]
}
```

Each **ProductOrder** component the user adds, has to be each item, **here is the problem**, I haven't been able to find a solution to separate each **ProductOrder** into an object and "push" it to an array.

I've been tried to create react states to store the object, but how do I separate these inputs from the others to create the object, and how do I make an object for each set of inputs?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, I think the idea of saving them in the state is the way to go. You don't show your current way, so I'll improvise. **Note** the code below is a concept; not actual working code.

```
function MyForm() {
    const [customOrders, setCustomOrders] = useState([])

    function addCustom() {
        // This object should match what your API needs
        customOrders.push({ id: Math.random(), text: "foo" })
    }

    // in your onSubmit handler, add customOrders to the other fields

    return (
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                {/* Other fields etc */}
            </fieldset>
            {customOrders.map(cm => <ProductOrder
                customOrders={customOrders}
                setCustomOrders={setCustomOrders}
                id={cm.id}
                key={cm.id}
            />)}
            <div>
                <span onClick={addCustom}>+</span>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

function ProductOrder({ customOrders, setCustomOrders, id }) {
    function handleTextChange(e) {
        const customOrdersCopy = [...customOrders]
        const order = customOrdersCopy.find(a => a.id === id)
        customOrdersCopy.text = e.value
        setCustomOrders(customOrdersCopy)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={handleTextChange} /> {id}
        </div>
    )
}
```